# Simple Node.js Troubleshooting - Receiving 404 from app.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, lua

I am attempting to deploy a node.js Heroku app which listens out for requests and will simply log the encoded string to the console. **Note:** I am limited to exporting data from my program in JSON, that's why I'm using `req.body`.

---

### JavaScript

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/um', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body[message]);
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('App listening!')
})
```

---

### Lua

```
local httpService = game:GetService('HttpService')
httpService:PostAsync("http://auto-attica.herokuapp.com/um", { "message" = "foo" })
```

---

Instead of logging text to the console. I receive Errors 404 both on the program running Lua and on the Heroku console.

```
2017-10-30T00:10:04.826245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/um" host=auto-attica.heroku-f35fbe137630 fwd="95.148.67.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=http
```

**and on the Lua console**

```
00:16:02.074 - HTTP 404 (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
00:16:02.074 - Stack Begin
00:16:02.075 - Script 'ServerScriptService.myOwnVanilla', Line 8
00:16:02.075 - Stack End
```

---

**Thank you very much for your time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a `GET` request in your express routes, but attempting to send a `POST` request to it which is what your Heroku log is showing you.

```
2017-10-30T00:10:04.826245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/um" 
                                                                ^^^^
```

May try setting up a `POST` handler:

```
app.post('/um', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body[message]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code above especially this line of code **req.body[message]**, I don't know  how you are getting that message in there. 
Why not send a response when you try to access that endpoint. Example is shown below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.get('/um', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Its working' });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('App listening!');
});
```

Comment: I am using req.body because the data I am passing in is encoded in the JSON format. I am attempting to pass through a value and not only detect the event.